# ReactJS CSS style Strangely get carried over to other component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've got this problem in ReactJS where if I Set a background color of a Body element in one page component, the color is still there when I route to other component which is not using that particular CSS.

So for example I have a welcome component which import a welcome.css that styles the background color of the body element. Then when I route to other component by clicking Link in navigation to let say contact-us component, the background color is still there on contact-us even thou contact-us does not import the welcome.css.
But in the first place if I never visit the welcome, and directly visit the contact-us, on a fresh tab, the coloring is obviously not there.

Code example:

**welcome.css**

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(310deg, #1b2753, #836538);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './assets/css/style/welcome.css';

function Welcome() {
    return (
        <>
            <H1>Welcome !</H1>
            <Link to="/contact-us">Contact Us</Link>
        </>
    );
}

export default Welcome;
```

**ContactUs.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function ContactUs() {
    return (
        <>
            <H1>Contact Us</H1>
        </>
    );
}

export default ContactUs;
```

Comment: We'll need to see code to tell you any details, but CSS stylesheets are global. Once a css file has been loaded, any element on the page which matches the selector will get the style. There are some techniques that can make a facsimile of local CSS, basically by renaming the selectors during a compile step, but that doesn't happen by default (eg, CSS modules).

Comment: Sorry I just got a chance to update and give code example. From that code example I only imported the css in the welcome.js, but when I navigate to ContactUs.js the body background gradient persist. But if I just directly go to ContactUs.js no body styling, normal.

Comment: Where are `Welcome` and `ContactUs` rendered?

Comment: @ksav I dont quite get the question. my index.js render App.js in Root div element, and in my App.js I've got browser router.

Comment: Component styles should not be allowed to affect the global scope, or affect the styles of other components. You may be interested in https://getbem.com/introduction/

Comment: I suggest you move your route specific styles and markup into the route components files and refactor your app in a way that does not rely on styling the document body differently per each route.

Comment: Yup it looks like, I use a wrong concept in programming this. Noted shouldn't style global scope element from component styles.

Answer (score 1):

In react, css stylesheets are global, so it will apply that css everywhere in the toold wherever that selector is used.
To avoid that use Css modules or give unique names to every selectors.

Comment: but I can't add classname to body element because body element is in index HTML right? while all jsx component will render inside body, then inside div id=root.

Comment: right now the closes answer is this, I simply remove the styling to body and move it to antoher div element wit specific classname. But still can't solve a problem if I "MUST" style the body.

Answer (score -1):

in this case, its better to use [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).

Example: Make your component specific css with `<name>.module.css` and import in all required components, then use `import styles from './Button.module.css';` and use `${style.<class-name>}`

Comment: the thing is we can't give classname to body element right? that's why i think to style body element I need to style it with external css and import the css.